# Single-spa not working on browser Chrome and Edge, but it works on Firefox browser

Tags: single-spa

I do practice Single-spa based on the blog. https://lazypandatech.com/blog/Microfrontend/10/Create-Microfrontend-Application-using-Single-SPA-framework.
the problem is the application loading of single-spa only works well on Firefox. but it has issue on Chrome and Edge with below Error:

*load.js:96 ==>single-spa minified message #37: See [https://single-spa.js.org/error/?code=37&arg=application&arg=single-spa&arg={"NOT_LOADED":"NOT_LOADED","LOADING_SOURCE_CODE":"LOADING_SOURCE_CODE","NOT_BOOTSTRAPPED":"NOT_BOOTSTRAPPED","BOOTSTRAPPING":"BOOTSTRAPPING","NOT_MOUNTED":"NOT_MOUNTED","MOUNTING":"MOUNTING","MOUNTED":"MOUNTED","UPDATING":"UPDATING","UNMOUNTING":"UNMOUNTING","LOAD_ERROR":"LOAD_ERROR","SKIP_BECAUSE_BROKEN":"SKIP_BECAUSE_BROKEN"}](https://single-spa.js.org/error/?code=37&arg=application&arg=single-spa&arg=%7B%22NOT_LOADED%22:%22NOT_LOADED%22,%22LOADING_SOURCE_CODE%22:%22LOADING_SOURCE_CODE%22,%22NOT_BOOTSTRAPPED%22:%22NOT_BOOTSTRAPPED%22,%22BOOTSTRAPPING%22:%22BOOTSTRAPPING%22,%22NOT_MOUNTED%22:%22NOT_MOUNTED%22,%22MOUNTING%22:%22MOUNTING%22,%22MOUNTED%22:%22MOUNTED%22,%22UPDATING%22:%22UPDATING%22,%22UNMOUNTING%22:%22UNMOUNTING%22,%22LOAD_ERROR%22:%22LOAD_ERROR%22,%22SKIP_BECAUSE_BROKEN%22:%22SKIP_BECAUSE_BROKEN%22%7D) Module
zone.js:209 ==> Uncaught Error: application 'single-spa' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: undefined

Main.js:1 ==> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED*

How to enable it and can be view on Chrome and Edge? Does any security issue on chrome & edge on handling the single-spa js files?